# Haskell: How to use a HashMap in a main function

Tags: haskell, hashmap

I beg for your help, speeding up the following program:

```
main = do
  jobsToProcess <- fmap read getLine
  forM_ [1..jobsToProcess] $ \_ -> do
    [r, k] <- fmap (map read . words) getLine :: IO [Int]
    putStrLn $ doSomeReallyLongWorkingJob r k
```

There could(!) be a lot of identical jobs to do, but it's not up to me modifying the inputs, so I tried to use `Data.HashMap` for backing up already processed jobs. I already optimized the algorithms in the `doSomeReallyLongWorkingJob` function, but now it seems, it's quite as fast as C.

But unfortunately it seems, I'm not able to implement a simple cache without producing a lot of errors. I need a simple cache of Type `HashMap (Int, Int) Int`, but everytime I have too much or too few brackets. And IF I manage to define the cache, I'm stuck in putting data into or retrieving data from the cache cause of lots of errors.

I already Googled for some hours but it seems I'm stuck. BTW: The result of the `longrunner` is an `Int` as well.

Comment: Calm down... Please first explain the problem. Apparently you want to process jobs, but want some kind of uniqueness filter. Right?

Comment: No, I don't need a uniqueness filter, because I must write an answer for every input. 10 jobs in, 10 answers out. In the same order. I simply need a cache.

Comment: Ah memoization so to speak?

Comment: Exactly. And I thought, a HashMap would be the best solution for this.

Comment: You can definitely use a HashMap here, just check if the key is in the map yet, if it is then you're done, otherwise execute the action and store its result in the HashMap.

Comment: @Hennes: are you allowed to use packages, because there are elegant solutions for this.

Comment: @bheklilr That was my intention indeed. But I'm stuck with the syntax.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: I have access to all "standard" packages, like e.g. Data.HashMap.Lazy but getting "new" packages in production is a very complicated (read: bureaucratic) procedure.

Comment: @Hennes: I suppose `memoize` (`Data.Function.Memoize`) is not one of them? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize-0.8.1/docs/Data-Function-Memoize.html

Comment: Pity, no. Just checked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple to make a stateful action that caches operations. First some boilerplate:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Debug.Trace
```

I'll use `Data.Map`, but of course you can substitute in a hash map or any similar data structure without much trouble. My long-running computation will just add up its arguments. I'll use `trace` to show when this computation is executed; we'll hope not to see the output of the `trace` when we enter a duplicate input.

```
reallyLongRunningComputation :: [Int] -> Int
reallyLongRunningComputation args = traceShow args $ sum args
```

Now the caching operation will just look up whether we've seen a given input before. If we have, we'll return the precomputed answer; otherwise we'll compute the answer now and store it.

```
cache :: (MonadState (Map a b) m, Ord a) => (a -> b) -> a -> m b
cache f x = do
    mCached <- gets (M.lookup x)
    case mCached of
        -- depending on your goals, you may wish to force `result` here
        Nothing -> modify (M.insert x result) >> return result
        Just cached -> return cached
    where
    result = f x
```

The `main` function now just consists of calling `cache reallyLongRunningComputation` on appropriate inputs.

```
main = do
    iterations <- readLn
    flip evalStateT M.empty . replicateM_ iterations
        $   liftIO getLine
        >>= liftIO . mapM readIO . words
        >>= cache reallyLongRunningComputation
        >>= liftIO . print
```

Let's try it in ghci!

```
> main
5
1 2 3
[1,2,3]
6
4 5
[4,5]
9
1 2
[1,2]
3
1 2
3
1 2 3
6
```

As you can see by the bracketed outputs, `reallyLongRunningComputation` was called the first time we entered `1 2 3` and the first time we entered `1 2`, but not the second time we entered these inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i'm not too far off base, but first you need a way to carry around the past jobs with you. Easiest would be to use a foldM instead of a forM.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe

main = do
  jobsToProcess <- fmap read getLine
  foldM doJobAcc acc0 [1..jobsToProcess] 
  where
    acc0 = --initial value of some type of accumulator, i.e. hash map
    doJobAcc acc _ = do
      [r, k] <- fmap (map read . words) getLine :: IO [Int]
      case getFromHash acc (r,k) of
         Nothing -> do 
           i <-  doSomeReallyLongWorkingJob r k
           return $ insertNew acc (r,k) i
         Just i -> do
            return acc
```

Note, I don't actually use the interface for putting and getting the hash table key. It doesn't actually have to be a hash table, Data.Map from containers could work. Or even a list if its going to be a small one.

Another way to carry around the hash table would be to use a State transformer monad.

Comment: So I insert my putStrLn directly before each of the "returns"?

Comment: Just for my couriosity: Can you tell me, how to do the same thing with a State Monad?

Comment: yes and yes. but i probably cant update you this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding this answer since I feel like the other answers are diverging a bit from the original question, namely using hashtable constructs in Main function (inside IO monad).

Here is a minimal hashtable example using [hashtables](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables-1.2.1.1/docs/Data-HashTable-IO.html) module. To install the module with cabal, simply use

> cabal install hashtables

In this example, we simply put some values in a hashtable and use lookup to print a value retrieved from the table.

```
import qualified Data.HashTable.IO as H

main :: IO ()
main = do
        t <- H.new :: IO (H.CuckooHashTable Int String)
        H.insert t 22 "Hello world"
        H.insert t 5 "No problem"
        msg <- H.lookup t 5
        print msg
```

Notice that we need to use explicit type annotation to specify which implementation of the hashtable we wish to use.